# Django settings in migrations

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to access the Django settings from a migration?  I'm attempting to load large data files (not fixtures within my project) into my database via a data migration.  I would like the root directory of the data files to be configurable and the ability to read the path of the root directory from within my migration.

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

in you migration file type:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

now you have access to your settings